# ModuleNotFoundError on Python IDLE

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

[image]

The first one is that I've been having these errors since months ago. Every time I try to run these in python IDLE, it shows these kinds of errors. But it runs just fine when using terminal(python3 file-name.py). I've been anchoring interests in so many things and maybe I might have installed something unnecessary and that's bugging me.

Comment: What I think is that you have 2 pythons, that is, you have installed a python that has the packages and you invoke it through the terminal and another python is the one you use in IDLE which does not have those packages installed

Comment: I do have both of the python versions. But I do always use pip3 or python3 to install the packages and modules.

Comment: you can have 50 python2 and 50 python3, and each one has its pip that will install the package in the python that it manages. That is to say that the python of the terminal and the python of IDLE have the same version does not imply that they are the same python

Comment: Since python, not IDLE, is responsible for running python code, including imports, eyllanesc is likely right, as has been the case with multiple other questions like this.  `import sys; sys.executable` in both interactive python and IDLE will tell you what python is running, and hence whether you are using the same binary in the same directory.  `python3 -m idlelib` will start IDLE with the python linked to 'python3' .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the python path from IDLE:

Example:

```
import sys
for path in sys.path:
    print(path)
```

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\Lib\idlelib`

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python37.zip`

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\DLLs`

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib`

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64`

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages`

List the python path where IDLE is referring

Referring IDLE outputs, Go to Scripts path in CMD (Run as Administartor):

example:
`cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\Scripts`

Here, you can do `pip install <module_name>`
Then IDLE will refer this module