# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy'" even though I installed it via pip

Tags: python, pip, spacy

I'm fairly new to python so this is probably a simple solution but I just dont get it.
I just installed the module "spacy" via cmd in the directory where my python script is located as well. I used the following commands:

```
pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
pip install -U spacy
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

Then, I tried to import the module in my python(3.11.0)  (via IDLE 64-bit).

With every command, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import spacy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy'
```

Does the module require a special version of something? I know that one other student in my class could import the module instantly.

Thank you!

I used this command:

```
import spacy
```

I also used some other commands online such as

```
from spacy.en import English
```

and

```
python3 -m pip install -U spacy==2.3.5
```

and other versions of "spacy". I tried to execute the command both via the shell and the script.

EDIT: I had to use python 3.10 instead of 3.11, then it worked

Comment: What happens if you run your script from the command line? You are most likely using a different python environment in IDLE than you use in the command line.

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54676126/modulenotfounderror-on-python-idle

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53258737/how-to-solve-modulenotfound-error-in-idle

Comment: Have you tried `pip3 install spacy`

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65562063/python-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-requests

Comment: Note that I found all of these by googling "python idle ModuleNotFoundError: No module named". There are many more hits on other sites than Stack Overflow any of which will help you solve your problem. Often googling the error message will lead to results. In this case I added a couple of words to the search phrase to help narrow it down.

Comment: If I run the script via cmd, it works (at least the spacy module). But in IDLE it still doesn't work. I have no idea what would be the reason, isn't it the same file that is getting run? Or should you generally run scripts via cmd?

Comment: EDIT: I un- and re-installed python and now spacy is working in neither cmd nor python